# Tag Synonym Request: Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently multiple tags covering Ubuntu On Windows. This proposal aims to bring them all into a single centralized (and easy to use) tag.

As such, I'd like to request that [wsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wsl) be used for all posts about the Ubuntu on Windows system, so it should be a synonym for [bash-on-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash-on-windows) and [ubuntu-on-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows).

Furthermore, I propose that [wsl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wsl) be the central tag for questions about the Ubuntu on Windows project, as it's memorable and short. It is also [in use by other sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326440/792066), so it would make sense for us to follow suit.

I am unable to request this synonym myself, as I do not have enough votes and it seems to be a controversial split.

Comment: Maybe take guidance from SO?

Comment: I agree with this. They're the same thing, and it would help unify the category if some OP only put in one or the other.

Comment: Would `Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux` not be a better choice than both? That seems to be its official name. Here is another one to add as synonym `ubuntu-on-windows` http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows

Comment: @MarkKirby It may be its official name, but I personally still think it isn't quite as recognizable as `bash-on-windows`. It's pretty obvious what that means, but those who don't know (which included me until recently) what `wsl` or `Windows-Subsystem-for-Linux` might have trouble finding any tags to put in, and may end up just using `windows` and `bash` together.

Comment: Is `bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-via-windows-subsystem-for-linux` too long ;p

Comment: @MarkKirby I think "Subsystem" is too old-school, too-technical and too-misleading at the same time. If you strike the word your tag becomes "Windows-for-Linux" which seems appropriate as Micro$oft has smelled the coffee and will add more than bash as it wakes up. Indeed Ubutnu could have been classified as "Windows for Linux" in a generic way. M$ wants a slice of the pie and will probably add EXT4 next week :P

Comment: I think WSL should be the main tag, as it will probably the simple name for this system on the long run, it's the acronym Microsoft uses, and follows SO. Possible synonyms: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-on-windows

Answer (score 8):

It's not "bash" on Windows. You can get dash on Windows, or zsh on windows, or Xorg on Windows. The whole "bash on windows" was more evidence to one of the three problems all programmers have: off by one errors and a less-than-passable naming sense.

Just saying "bash on Windows" opens a host of problems that we shouldn't have, like generic bash problems getting the tag because it's "on Windows", or stuff that is specific to the platform not getting the tag because it has nothing to do with "bash" or people tagging it *just because*.

The technology, in theory, would allow you to run any Linux binary on Windows, heck, you could just install pacman and manage your system as if it was Arch Linux... at such point, there isn't anything specific to "Ubuntu" on it, just that that's the default image you get. Forcing people that knows better, like the answerers, to follow the "wrong tag", because they know the correct terminology isn't productive in the long run. They are going to look for a Windows Subsystem for Linux tag and that's what we should deliver. [Stack Overflow already figured out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326440/792066), Super User didn't need a discussion, they [didn't create a bash-on-windows tag](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-linux-subsystem/synonyms) and I believe that's what we should follow.

BTW, there are less than 200 questions in the 3 sites combined, and we don't even have 20. Being the odd one out doesn't sit well.

Comment: I tried installing pacman in Ubuntu. Found really interesting result